Relative pronoun with "man"
I'm practicing making some sentences with relative clauses.
I wrote this

In dieser Zeit muss man alle Informationen, die er hört,
hinterfragen, besonders auf Social Media.

Chat GPT suggested that it is more natural to write it like this

In dieser Zeit muss man alle Informationen, die man hört,
hinterfragen, besonders auf Social Media.

To me it looks really redundant to repeat "man" twice, but GPT says that because man is a generic impersonal subject, introducing a definite article "er" is not appropriate.
Which version is better?

If it was "sie" instead of "man" you wouldn't suddenly switch to "er" either. It only becomes interesting if you need a form besides Nominativ.

And by the way, the relative pronoun in your example sentence is "die".

ChatGPT is exactly right. Because "man" is an impersonate pronoun, you cannot refer to it with a personate one from the relative clause. Using "er" in the relative clause is just wrong.

Ok, thanks for the input! But doesn't repeating "man" twice sound a bit redundant?

Nope, it doesn't. Articles and pronouns are just normal to show up in groups in German.

It's the same rule as in English: "At this time, one must question all the information one hears, especially on social media." The word "one" is repeated.

PS. I'm pretty sure this forum counts as "social media", so question everything you hear on this site as well.

@RDBury True, I guess it does work the same way in English. Although to me saying "one" feels quite fancy and elevated, I would use "you" 9/10 times, whereas in German "man" seems to be much more common.

@AlexErmolin Languages usually don't optimize to remove redundancy. It can be redundant and correct at the same time :)

@JonathanHerrera Well, actually, languages typically optimize towards more redundancy (within limits), normally. Everything to get the message across helps. (Or why would someone say "I love you very, very much - Over the moon and back" when a simple "I love you" would do....)

@AlexErmolin If you prefer you over one you can write: "At this time, you must question all the information you hear, especially on social media."

@Alex Ermolin - Yes, "one" is unusual, and I thought about "you" as well. But there is no rule for "you" since the 2nd person pronoun is still you. It's kind of a quirk of English that it can be used as an impersonal pronoun even though grammatically it's still 2nd person, The sentence is ambiguous with "you" since we don't know if it's addressed to a single person or people in general; we can only tell from context.
